# iPad Mini with retina shows memory issues in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, xcode5

I have run an application in various apple device. 
First i run the application in `iPhone 4 - ios 7.0.3` Now i test the memory allocation using Instruments. it shows [image: iPhone 4 - ios 7.0.3]
Now i run the application in `iPad 2 - ios 7.0.2` Now it shows the memory like this,
[image: iPad 2 - ios 7.0.2]
Now i run the application in `iPhone 5c - ios 7.0.3` Now it shows the memory like this,
[image: iPhone 5c - ios 7.0.3]
AtLast now i run the same application in `iPad Mini Retina - ios 7.0.3`, Now it shows the memory like this, [image: iPad Mini Retina - ios 7.0.3]

My question is, why this device takes this much of memory while i launch the application. The issue is, app will crashed.

Comment: Did you try iPhone 5S, the other 64-bit system?

Comment: You really should provide some more details and code to what your app does on startup. Otherwise we can only do wild guesses, like: do you show a high resolution image on startup that will likely use much more memory on an retina iPad display than on others.

Comment: @Kerni - am doing view animations (Block Object) while my home screen is loaded.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Thanks for ur reply, I tried in iPhone 5S also, it shows 13 mb of memory only.